username.github.io is 404 not founded
Something wrong while I used Github to build my own blog by hexo. It was always successfully until after "hexo d". I suspect the problem was I changed the name of the initial branch in new repositories when I downloaded Git.Because I found one difference between the success example and mine.
Thank you for answering.



And I tried to change the default branch of GitHub to the new name and use the web by adding the branch,it still did not work. So did I doubt right and how to work out it?
